# Tomcat read file exception java

Tags: java, tomcat, io

I am trying to read file on TomCat start up. Unfortunatelly it is throws IO exception, complaining about file which is not found.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
`file:\C:\_home\main\IntelliBid\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\intellibid-service\WEB-INF\classes\xxx-privatekey.p12 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`
```

This is my code which I am using to read a file:

```
URL filePath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("xxx-privatekey.p12");
final GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(filePath.toString()))
        .build();
```

I've checked filepath from `URI` file path is actually correct!

Could you please help me to resolve current problem? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the file path exactly equal?

Comment: You can't treat opaque file references received from the classloader an system file paths. You either need to use the stream directly or copy the stream to a file manually.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, not sure what do you mean, could you please provide an example?

Comment: There you go - an example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works!